# How to avoid adding 0 in database in sql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a Form database with connected to php coding.
the problem is when i modify the php code a default value '0' is adding in data base..
i need the suggestion to avoid that....

Comment: To get higher quality answers, write a [higher quality question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) by including [sample code](http://sscce.org/) that is complete yet concise, including SQL statements defining tables and inserting sample data. See also [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that field is declared as integer in the db and you do not allow null values,
when you post the values of the form and there isn't a value for that field, it will take the default value for integers "0".

To avoid that you need to allow null values and you need to check while you update the record if a value for tha field exists.

```
if(isset($_POST['yourVar'])) {
    $value = intval($_POST['yourVar']);
}
else {
    $value = null;
}
```

Something like that.